# UICollectionViewController multithread image loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm having trouble loading images asyncronously between my view controllers. I have a tableView controller that opens up a collection view controller when you click on a row. When the collection view opens, it hangs for a while as the images are downloaded from the internet.

I put the following code in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:, but this results in synchronous loading, and makes the program lag.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CollectionCell";
  CollectionCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[self.theImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  cell.itemImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

  return cell;
}
```

My question is, **where** and **how** do I implement code such that the collection view loads the empty cells while the images are downloading (and then appear after they download)?

I tried to use grand central dispatch but I couldn't quite figure out. If someone could help point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You want to download the image asynchronously on a thread, that is not the main thread. Look at the `IconDownloader` from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_IconDownloader_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Classes_IconDownloader_m-DontLinkElementID_6

Comment: I have multiple images in the collectionview, and all are bigger than an icon's size. Would this still be applicable?

Comment: Yes of course it does. It is exactly what you're looking for ;)

Comment: Quick question, the sample uses a tableView as an example, so they just use 
`UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:iconDownloader.indexPathInTableView];`
since I'm using collectionView, I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell`, called `CollectionCell`. How do I modify the code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that kind of lazy loading, I always use:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

This solves most of my problems when I want to async load images in tables/collectionviews etc.

It supports caching of images already downloaded and just saves a lot of headaches.

Comment: Is this better than using the method Boris mentioned?

Comment: It's probably the same, but it takes a lot of code and testing out of your hands. It's a framework that does most of the work for you.

Comment: This made things actually really simple, thanks! I have one question, I have an array of strings, but when I run it, I get the error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd8821c0'`

However, when I manually fill in `setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com/img.jpg"]`,  I don't get the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Turns out the complier was interpreting the object as `NSURL` despite being an `NSString` object. I casted it to an `NSString` using `[myURL absoluteString];`

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see your question there, but glad you solved it.